# Difference between initramfs.cpio and rootfs.cpio

Tags: initramfs, root-filesystem

What are the differnces between the two?

Can I just use initramfs.cpio or do I need to use both?

Actually my rootfs.cpio file is 7 Mb and initramfs.cpio is just 0.5mb, so I was thinking if I can use initramfs.cpio only or not

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled). 
Most systems just mount another filesystem over rootfs and ignore it.  The
amount of space an empty instance of ramfs takes up is tiny.

Linux kernels contain a gzipped "cpio" format archive, which is
extracted into rootfs when the kernel boots up.  After extracting, the kernel
checks to see if rootfs contains a file "init", and if so it executes it as PID
1.  If found, this init process is responsible for bringing the system the
rest of the way up, including locating and mounting the real root device (if
any).  If rootfs does not contain an init program after the embedded cpio
archive is extracted into it, the kernel will fall through to the older code
to locate and mount a root partition, then exec some variant of /sbin/init
out of that.